# Carousel Slider with query loop inside for featured custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to get a carousel slider to display 3 posts at a time through a loop for featured custom posts type.

This is the code that I have for the carousel:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Featured Posts</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-8'>
      <div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item  active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>        
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>        
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>      
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#media" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#media" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
      </div>                          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just want to display the thumbnails with the permalink for the following query:

```
<?php
    $featured = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'franchisings',
        'posts_per_page' => '3',
        'meta_key' => 'meta-checkbox',
        'meta_value' => 'yes' 
    ) );

if ($featured->have_posts()): while($featured->have_posts()): $featured->
    the_post(); ?>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">

<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a> 

        </div>
 </div>


        <?php
endif;
endwhile; else:
endif;
?>
```

I don't want to use plugins, and I'm using the bootstrap framework. And this is what I'm going for, but with the featured posts' thumbnails instead:

[image: Goal]

I can get the featured post types to display but I can't get them properly inside the carousel.

Can you help out? Thanks

**CODE UPDATED WITH @UCHENG ANSWER**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
         <h3>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outlined btn-theme btn-lg" id="button" data-wow-delay="0.7s">Franchisings em Destaque</a>
        </h3>
        <div class='col-md-8'>
      <div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item  active">

    <?php
        $featured = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'franchisings',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'meta_key' => 'meta-checkbox',
            'meta_value' => 'yes' 
        ) );

     $counter = 0;
        if ( $featured->have_posts()): while( $featured->have_posts() ): $featured->the_post(); ?>

                <?php if ( $counter%3 == 0 ): ?>
                 <div class="item <?php if ( $counter == 0 ): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
                    <div class="row">
                <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(200, 200)); ?>
                            <?php $counter++; ?>
                        </a> 
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                   <?php if ( $counter%3 == 0 ):?>
                    </div> 
                 </div><!--end item-->
                <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile;endif;

         ?>
```

Comment: Please, show us the HTML output that is being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `posts_per_page` as -1 to get all posts.

```
<div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <h2>Featured Posts</h2>
      </div>

      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-8'>
          <div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
            <div class="carousel-inner">

           <?php 
            $featured = new WP_Query( array( 
                'post_type' => 'franchisings',
                'posts_per_page' => '-1',//-1 to get all posts
                'meta_key' => 'meta-checkbox',
                'meta_value' => 'yes' 
            ) );     

            $counter = 0;
            if ( $featured->have_posts()): while( $featured->have_posts() ): $featured->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php if ( $counter%3 == 0 ): ?>
                     <div class="item <?php if ( $counter == 0 ): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
                        <div class="row">
                    <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                <?php $counter++; ?>
                            </a> 
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                       <?php if ( $counter%3 == 0 ):?>
                        </div> 
                     </div><!--end item-->
                    <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endwhile;endif;


            </div><!--carousel-inner-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--end row-->

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've managed to get the code together and have it display the posts I want. I've updated the question with the code altogether with the loop inside the carousel. However I'm still having a problem, as it displays all posts together instead of inserting in the slider: [link](http://prntscr.com/d6syux). How can I get it to put the 4th image in the next area of the slider?

Comment: Do you want to add 4th image to each item? You need to change the class col-md-4 to col-md-3 and change $counter%3 to $counter%4.

Comment: No, I can have just 3 images per item, I can't get the 4th image to go to the next slider. I don't know if you understand what I'm saying. The 4th image goes to the bottom of the 1st image, like in the image I showed in the link. I need the carousel to be continuous

Comment: I update my answer, please refer to the HTML. In your HTML, you should not put the loop inside the  <div class="item  active">.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, now the images are right :)

Answer (score 0):

<del>There is no carousel component in Bootstrap 3</del>, but you can try carousel in [Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/).

In most of my projects, I use [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) to make this effect. It' easy to use and has lots options to customize, of course, it's responsive.

**Pre-Step**

Please enqueue the owl-carousel js and css by using *wp_enqueue_script* hook.

**The Html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Featured Posts</h2>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-8'>
      <div class="owl-carousel" id="media">

            <div class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
            <div class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
            <div class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
            <div class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
            <div class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
            <div class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
            <div class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
            <div class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
            <div class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>

        </div>
      </div>                          
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
#media {
  width: 500px
}
```

**The JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#media").owlCarousel({
     items : 3,
  });

});
```

The demo on CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGNqNa

For more customize options, please check owl-carousel website: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not actually having problems with the html for the carousel, it's working. The problem I'm having is with getting the query loop inside the carousel. I can get one thumbnail from the query inside the carousel but I can't get it to loop.

Your reply does't help me doing what I want, and I leave you a link that shows that Bootstrap 3 has carousel 

[link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)
[link](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/kEK7M)

Comment: Thank you for providing the link. I add a new answer